# "Office Workers Demand More Parking" in SimTower

Tags: simtower

Here's another old game I've never quite mastered.  In Sim Tower, I can always make it almost to the end, but I trip at the finish line.

Once I reach 5 star status, I keep increasing my population and buy the cathedral on the roof like you're supposed to.  I get as much parking as I'm allowed (it eventually tells you cannot build any more of the item).  And, even if I delete all of my offices (or at least most of them), I get the message that the office workers demand more parking.  And, as long as I have that complaint, it won't upgrade me to "Tower" status.

Am I missing a key strategy?  Or is this just a bug?  If it's a bug, is there any patch for it?

Comment: Doesn't "Tower" come once a wedding is held in the cathedral? Not sure what the prerequisites are for that once you've build one. Random maybe?

Comment: Weddings and >15000 pop (as answered below).

Comment: Maybe your offices aren't connected to the parking...
Also why ever build condos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some walktrough guides advise you to ignore this, so the message you're having may be true be there is nothing you can do about it (and I haven't found any patch to correct this.

To upgrade to "Tower" you will need 15000 population and wait for a wedding to take place.

To achieve 15000 population you will probably need to erase some condos slowly and build offices until you ran out of stairs (because using some stairs to offices levels will help).

If you're bankrupt deleting condos just wait until all offices are re-rented. Lower the prices of some of them don't rent at all.

It can take a long time to achieve it, but then you'll see it in the cathedral if I remember correctly. Good luck !